# How to split up a class

Tags: design

Let's say I have a `Migrator` class to run DB migrations. It also has functionality to lock the db and make sure nothing else can run at the same time.

I now have another piece of functionality that also needs to lock the db.

Should I:

- just make `lockDb()` public?
- split the class into `Migrator` and `Locker`?
- split the class into `Migrator` and `Locker`, and also rewrite the tests to be two separate unit tests rather than a single integration test?

Comment: How can you have functionality in Migrator that makes sure nothing else can operate the DB? For locking to be effective you must already have some thing that is accessible by both Migrator and "the other piece of functionality". And the other piece would have to be co-operative. So I am curious to how your current lock is implemented.

Comment: this is an arbitrary example, the question is about design not databases

Comment: I see. So you do not actually have a class that locks something, right? My point is that would be impossible without already having some shared thingy so your initial situation is not real. You cannot have a private lock. So the question "should I make it pubic?" makes no sense. It could only be a lock if it would already be public.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the locking functionality should be implemented on the database itself.

Otherwise you would be able to replace the Locker class with another implementation and no longer have a guaranteed lock.

If the function, say a transaction is already implemented in the database driver or component you are using to access the DB then there is no need to abstract it out.

If however you have been forced to implement your own custom locking procedure which needs to be shared between components. then yes you should separate it into its own library